# Subset and remove excluded distinct values

Tags: r, subset

I need to get rid of excluded values when I subset a data frame. That is, if I call summary in the example below `z` should not appear as distinct value of `name2, and is there a possibility to let the ids start at 1 for the subset?

```
bspframestring<-( "id,name1,name2,v1,v2,v3,v4
 1,1,z,1,1,5,1
 2,2,z,0,1,8,1
 3,2,y,0,4,0,5 
 4,1,y,5,3,4,4
 5,2,y,4,9,5,5")

bspframe<-read.table(textConnection(bspframestring),
                     header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names="id")

bspframesub<-subset(bspframe,name2=="y",select=c("name1","name2","v2"))

summary(bspframesub)

#     name1       name2       v2       
# Min.   :1.000   y:3   Min.   :3.000  
# 1st Qu.:1.500   z:0   1st Qu.:3.500  
# Median :2.000         Median :4.000  
# Mean   :1.667         Mean   :5.333  
# 3rd Qu.:2.000         3rd Qu.:6.500  
# Max.   :2.000         Max.   :9.000  

row.names(bspframesub)

# [1] "3" "4" "5"
```

Comment: What language is this? Maybe tagging your question with the language would get you more help?

Comment: Sorry, first stackoverflow question. The language is R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
summary(droplevels(bspframesub))
```

And to make the factor-level consolidation permanent, need to assign the result:

```
bspframesub <- droplevels(bspframesub)
```

There's also a `rownames<-` function which could be given a `1:now(bspframesub)` argument. You can also give it a NULL argument which gets you back the default values:

```
> row.names(bspframesub) <- NULL
> row.names(bspframesub)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```